# CreateFile method for Windows Store 8.1 not working

Tags: windows, windows-phone

I am using CreateFile2 method for Windows phone 8.1 and it is working fine. But when i am trying to use the similar method i.e CreateFile for Windows Store 8.1, it is giving error.

// for windows phone 8.1

```
hFile = ::CreateFile2(wzFilePath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, CREATE_ALWAYS, &extendedParams);
```

// for windows store 8.1

```
hFile = CreateFile( abCmdFile, // file name 
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, // open r-w 
    0,                    // do not share 
    NULL,                 // default security 
    CREATE_ALWAYS,        // overwrite existing
    FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,// normal file 
    NULL);                // no template
```

The errors are:

a) 'CreateFile': identifier not found.

b)    IntelliSense: identifier "CreateFile" is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) near the bottom of the page, in the table, it is said it only supports desktop apps. If you want to create file in an windows store app you need to use [MSDN CreateFile2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422(v=vs.85).aspx), CreateFile is not allowed in widows store/phone apps.